# Two counters - overflow handling in both directions

Tags: binary, vhdl, fpga

I am designing a system where I have 2 18-bit counters and I want to keep track of the difference of these two by subtracting them.

The inputs:

```
A   : in    unsigned(18 downto 0); -- Counter 1
B   : in    unsigned(18 downto 0); -- Counter 2
```

The variables I use to convert to signed numbers with an extra bit:

```
variable As : signed(19 downto 0);
variable Bs : signed(19 downto 0);
variable Ys : signed(19 downto 0);
```

The subtraction in a process which is performed on every rising edge on the clock:

```
As := signed('0' & A);             -- The two stored values are converted to signed number signals. 
Bs := signed('0' & B);
Ys := As - Bs;                     -- The difference is calculated.
```

The sign is important because I need to know which one is leading or lagging the other.

This works as far as the counters are not wrapped around, which leads to my question: How can I handle this in VHDL, when I also need to know the direction of the wraps (the counters can also count down)?

I am already thinking of a solution which includes a lot of big comparators to detect the wraps, but there might be a more "low cost" solution in terms of logic elements?

Note: The counters are modulo 409600, so 409599 will be the max value.
They are incremental but do also have an asynchronous load, so in one clock they can vary up to +- 205 counts because the load value to each of the counters is value+205 or value-205.

Thank you for guiding me in the right direction :)

Comment: I twitched at "have an asynchronous load". Such a thing should not exist, asynchronous set/reset is fine, so is synchronous load, but asynchronous load yield a sub-optimal circuit that's asking for trouble. For your wrap-around detection problem, I'd say modify the counters to report the wraps around and direction.

Answer (score 1):

The below does not handle modulo different from `2 ** N`, but may give you some ideas.

For `dist` as the shorted distance between `a` and `b`, and `a_ahead` if `a = b + dist` (with wrapping):

```
  signal a_sub_b : unsigned(a'range);
  signal a_ahead : std_logic;
  signal dist    : unsigned(a'range);
begin
  a_sub_b <= a - b;
  a_ahead <= not a_sub_b(a_sub_b'left);
  dist    <= a_sub_b when (a_ahead = '1') else (to_unsigned(0, a_sub_b'length) - a_sub_b);
```